# How to add a link in a image's caption?

Tags: images, links, captions, linking

I would like to add a link to the caption of a photo in one of my posts. I can type in the HTML for the link in the caption, but when I publish the post the link gets removed.

**How do you add a link to a caption?** This would be really useful for giving photo credit.

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer on question 3097](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/how-can-i-add-a-url-field-to-the-attachments-window/3108#3108) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to be able to use the media attachment's title, description, and maybe even the **permalink** and **image link** too. I felt that a caption specific hook should be added to the `media.php` file.

When I went to submit an enhancement request, it looked like someone beat me to it. Unfortunately, that was **four** years ago. I bumped it.

In the meantime, I published the [GIC plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gallery-image-captions/) to add this *caption* hook for me. Once the plugin is installed, you can write a *filter* to use more media attachment meta as your caption. With a filter, you can even add more styling or remove/hide the caption completely.

Here's an example filter that pulls in the image's **title**, **caption**, **description**, creates a **download** link, and adds some custom **styles**.

```
/**
 * Custom Filter for Gallery Image Captions
 */
function my_gallery_image_caption($attachment_id, $captiontag, $selector, $itemtag) {

    $id = $attachment_id;

    $my_image_meta = galimgcaps_get_image_meta($id);

    return "<{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='{$selector}-{$id}'>"
    . "<strong>" .  wptexturize($my_image_meta['title']) . "</strong><br><br>"
    .  wptexturize($my_image_meta['caption']) . "<br><br>"
    .  wptexturize($my_image_meta['description']) . "<br><br>"
    . "<strong>Alt Text</strong>: " . $my_image_meta['alt'] . "<br><br>"
    . "<a href='" . $my_image_meta['src'] . "' target='_blank'>Download Image</a>"
    . "</{$captiontag}></{$itemtag}>";

}
add_filter('galimgcaps_gallery_image_caption', 'my_gallery_image_caption', 10, 4);
```

Check out the documentation and examples to see if this works for you. Shout if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the link under the photo, on top of the photo, or when you click the photo is goes to the caption?

Comment: Under the photo and associated with the image in the caption field when you upload it and in your media gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Same question at wordpress support forum http://wordpress.org/support/topic/putting-a-link-in-an-image-caption .. see if these work around work for you.

Best of Luck.