# How to get all images url from gallery?

Tags: gallery

I created gallery in my post (in my custom post type) and now I need to get url of images from this gallery in my template file. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thx for your time.

Comment: Did you try 'post_gallery' filter hook? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin

Comment: Yes but this is too much complicated for me...

Comment: You've asked this again in another question. See bungeshea's answer. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78636/19683