# ID of images from gallery

Tags: attachments, gallery

Does anyone know how to get ID's of images from wordpress gallery in post? I have search entire internet and there is nothing to this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the IDs of which images are included in a gallery by switching to the **Text** editor tab and look for a piece of code like this:

```
[gallery columns="3" link="file" ids="615,619,618,617,616"]
```

The comma-separated list of image IDs are enclosed in the `ids` attribute

---

If you're looking to find out IDs of existing images in order to manually create a gallery, you can visit the *Media > Library* admin menu and click on the **Edit** link under an image. In your browser's address bar, you should see something similar to the following:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=622&action=edit
```

The number after `post=` is the image ID. In this case, the image ID is `622`.

Comment: I don't want to search ids manually... I need some loop for it.

Comment: So you want to retrieve the IDs of images attached to a gallery using PHP code?

Comment: I want to get images "src" so yes I want theyr id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that bungeshea is right and you want to retrieve the IDs of images attached to a gallery using PHP, you can filter `'shortcode_atts_gallery'`, like this:

```
add_filter ('shortcode_atts_gallery', 'wsec_filter_gallery_atts', 10, 3);

function wpsec_filter_gallery_atts ($out, $pairs, $atts) {
    $ids = $out['include'];
    // Do what you want with the ids
    return $out;
}
```