# How can we create a wallpapers gallery with different resolution?

Tags: gallery

I want to make a wallpaper gallery which can detect the screen resolution & give the option to download wallpapers in different resolution.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve you have to do:

1.[Get the screen resolution using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php)

2.[Customise the output of the WP image gallery shortcode](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin) or overide it by adding your gallery shortcode

Or

Search WordPress.org plugin directory.