# gallery image size

Tags: gallery

I have been looking for a couple of days for a filter for the WordPress gallery. I have tried many different codes but nothing seems to work for it. I am not using a plugin. I am talking about the stock gallery

I created a 2 column WordPress gallery and inserted it into a page. This did make a 2 column gallery but it also made the image sizes to 128 x 49. The site is responsive and the image sizes should be around 400 by 200. So I thought that if I could get WordPress to take out the inline height and width that the responsive part would take over and fill the available space. The filters that I have tried have worked on other images just not the gallery. I am using the 2014 theme and it's media queries. Is there a specific filter for the gallery?

Here is the filter I am using for other images

```
 add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'remove_img_width_height', 10, 1);

function remove_img_width_height($html) {
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)=\"\d*\"\s/', "", $html );
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [4343](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That post is talking about a plugin using shortcodes and limiting the amount of images posted. I tried the filter in that post and it didn't work.

Comment: You asked for a way to filter the WordPress gallery. `post_gallery` is that filter. You might need to adapt the specific filter to your purposes, but that's the right place to start.

Comment: @helgatheviking You should just mark it in a close vote, so we can inspect it. Thanks :)

Comment: Removing the inline tags will probably not help. CSS cam override those.

Comment: I would think post_gallery would work also. The strange thing is that when I put in that filter, the width and height is still there.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to removing the image sizes (which digging a little deeper looks very complicated), why not change the size of the images in your gallery?  If you use a larger image they will "fill the space" at larger screens and then shrink down for smaller screens.

The Gallery shortcode has a size parameter (with thumbnail as the default)... that is weirdly not available in the media library, but can be entered in the HTML editor.

```
[gallery link="none" ids="94,92,85" size="medium"]
```