# Custom Gallery HTML only working when images are attached to post/page

Tags: attachments, gallery

I have changed my gallery html using the posts_gallery hook in the same way as shown here:[How to customise the output of the WP image gallery shortcode from a plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/how-to-customise-the-output-of-the-wp-image-gallery-shortcode-from-a-plugin)

I've copied the latest code from wordpress and changed the $output variable to modify my html.  The problem is it only works for images that are attached to the page in question.  I want to use images from other pages or that have already been uploaded in galleries.

The galleries are generated with the short code using the media window and look like: [gallery ids="1,2,3,4,5"].  I've tried replacing ids with include but that doesn't work and I get some default code other than my custom html output.

Here is my custom gallery output:

```
function my_gallery_shortcode( $output = '', $atts, $content = false, $tag = false ) {
$return = $output; // fallback

// retrieve content of your own gallery function
$my_result = get_my_gallery_content( $atts );

// boolean false = empty, see http://php.net/empty
if( !empty( $my_result ) ) {
    $return = $my_result;
}

return $return;
}

add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_gallery_shortcode', 10, 4 );



function get_my_gallery_content ( $atts ) {

global $post;
// We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}

$html5 = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'gallery' );
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
    'itemtag'    => $html5 ? 'figure'     : 'dl',
    'icontag'    => $html5 ? 'div'        : 'dt',
    'captiontag' => $html5 ? 'figcaption' : 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => '',
    'link'       => '',
), $attr, 'gallery'));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
    $orderby = 'none';

if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$icontag = tag_escape($icontag);
$valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) )
    $itemtag = 'dl';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) )
    $captiontag = 'dd';
if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) )
    $icontag = 'dt';

$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';

/**
 * Filter whether to print default gallery styles.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param bool $print Whether to print default gallery styles.
 *                    Defaults to false if the theme supports HTML5 galleries.
 *                    Otherwise, defaults to true.
 */
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', ! $html5 ) ) {
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #{$selector} {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-item {
            float: {$float};
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: {$itemwidth}%;
        }
        #{$selector} img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
        /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
    </style>\n\t\t";
}

$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector-sausage' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class} images'>";

/**
 * Filter the default gallery shortcode CSS styles.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param string $gallery_style Default gallery shortcode CSS styles.
 * @param string $gallery_div   Opening HTML div container for the gallery shortcode output.
 */
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;
$first_image = reset($attachments);
$output .= '<a href="" itemprop="image" class="woocommerce-main-image zoom">';
$output .= wp_get_attachment_image( $first_image->ID, array(470,365), true, false );
$output .= '</a>';

$output .= '<div class="thumbnails">';

foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    if ( ! empty( $link ) && 'file' === $link )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false );
    elseif ( ! empty( $link ) && 'none' === $link )
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
    else
        $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

    $image_meta  = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );

    $orientation = '';
    if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) )
        $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';

    $output .= $image_output;
}

if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && $i % $columns !== 0 ) {
    $output .= "
        <br style='clear: both' />";
}

$output .= "
    </div>\n</div>\n";

return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing your attribute array to the `shortcode_atts` method. You're passing in an uninitialized variable.

Your function starts with

```
function get_my_gallery_content ( $atts ) {
```

But then you don't reference `$atts` again. The code is reading `$attr`, which is empty.

Change the line

```
), $attr, 'gallery'));
```

to

```
), $atts, 'gallery'));
```

You also need to change the following to match your argument variable name:

```
if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
    $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
    if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
        unset( $attr['orderby'] );
}
```

This code reads `$attr` but you're passing in `$atts`. Make sure they all match.

Because the array is empty, the logic falls back to only retrieving the current post's children. That's why you're only seeing those in your galleries.

Comment: Doh!!!  Can I simply change $atts to $attr at the beginning of my function? function get_my_gallery_content ( $attr ) {

Comment: Yep. That should do it. Leave the rest unchanged.