# How can I remove "<br style="clear: both">"

Tags: posts, gallery

I want to customise my output of the gallery. What I really do not need is

```
<br style="clear: both">
```

But it is there because I have to choice a number of columns during building the gallery in the backend. And according this choice it is print out.

But I only need it one time, at the end of the gallery.

For my custom output I would prefere something like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4358/152604). But using it my editor gives me errors eg. $id is not defined. And the WP Featherlight-Plugin is not working, too.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [`[gallery]` Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) will add that markup when necessary and *only* if the active WordPress theme didn't enable HTML5 support for the gallery Shortcode's markup/output. Or, in rare cases, a plugin or a custom code may have *disabled* the support.

So an easy way to get rid of that `<br>` tags, is by enabling HTML5 support for the Shortcode, like so: (add to the theme's `functions.php` file)

```
add_theme_support( 'html5', 'gallery' );
```

Or without enabling the HTML5 support, you can also use CSS to visually hide those `<br>` tags:

```
.gallery > br {
    display: none;
}
```

> For my custom output I would prefer something like
>   [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4358/152604).

In that case, you can copy the code in [`gallery_shortcode()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1631), which is the default callback function for the gallery Shortcode, and then just modify the gallery markup to your liking. Here's an example which I tried and tested working on WordPress 4.9.8: (full code [here](https://pastebin.com/FSCUcsLh))

```
// See gallery_shortcode() for reference.
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 3 );
function my_post_gallery( $output, $attr, $instance ) {
    $post = get_post();

    // Change #1: I commented out this part; use the passed $instance (see above).
    /*static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;*/

    ...

    // Change #2: I commented out this part; otherwise, the page would stop working.
    /*$output = apply_filters( 'post_gallery', '', $attr, $instance );
    if ( $output != '' ) {
        return $output;
    }*/

    ...

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {

        ...
        // Change #3: I commented out this code.
        /*if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 ) {
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
        }*/
    }

    // Change #4: I commented out this code.
    /*if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && $i % $columns !== 0 ) {
        $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both' />";
    }*/

    // Change #5: Here's the only one `br` tag we need.
    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both' />
        </div>\n";

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The `add_theme_support( 'html5', 'gallery' );` should in fact be `add_theme_support( 'html5', [ 'gallery' ] );` according to current docs.

Comment: Yes, thank you @NoviQ, you're right. But I'll keep the answer as-is for the time being. **To other readers, though, *use `add_theme_support( 'html5', [ 'gallery' ] )`*** - i.e. make sure the second parameter is an *array*. :)