# Custom Taxonomy With Author?

Tags: taxonomy

I have a picture website that has about 300 contributing authors. I want to have it so any author can submit a request of pictures that they want on a list. The list then would be credited to that author that submitted the list but the posts within the list are still associated with the author that submitted the picture. I can't seem to find a good plugin/work around that will do this.

Any ideas? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I posted a plugin once to [add artist information to media files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/how-can-i-add-a-url-field-to-the-attachments-window/3108#3108). You should be able to extend it easily. Then query for the post type attachment and the meta data you used to get the list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a plugin but when i faced a similar issue on one of my clients site, i needed to create an "in site favorites" feature for the site's users, and to do so i used a single usermeta filed were i saved the user's favorites.

First i create an "add to favorite" function which i displayed only to logged in users using the_content hook.

then i added another function to actually save the link in the users meta table (simpe ajax and using the add_user_meta function) all in one filed as an array of post ID's.

and last i create a new template page called "My Favorites" and asyou can tell by its name it showed the list of posts the current logged in user as saved as favorite , simply by grabbing the list of post ID's form the user meta.

So what I'm suggesing is maybe use the user meta as your list holder.