# Set a background color per image added to a post

Tags: images

When using a modal window such as lightbox or shadowbox to display a post's images, client would like to be able to choose the background color that would be used for the modal window according to the image to be shown: color would be either black, white or grey.

I'm thinking such hack should be done via a plugin but i didn't find any, so i guess i should do it myself. It scarces me a bit: where should i store the chosen value? What hooks ? Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the chosen color in a meta field. We have a question about [adding a custom field to attachments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/custom-fields-for-attachments), it contains an example. The hooks you need are `attachment_fields_to_edit` and `attachment_fields_to_save`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a plugin for this.

After uploading and inserting an image into a post, you can then click on the top left icon of the picture which brings you a new panel. Click on the "Advanced Settings" tab, there you can add html classes to the img tag.

You can then put in your css that bg1 = grey, bg2 = black, …

More info here > http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/image-settings/

Comment: Not as userfriendly as required by customer but a good idea nonetheless (customer wants a 1-click option GUI )