# Limit post view and management to custom user meta information

Tags: editor

I added custom user meta information called "schools" and I want the editors to only be able to manage posts made by other users who are from the same school. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi and welcome, Ronald. You are expected to show research efforts and/or the attempts you made to solve it yourself (see [about], [ask], [faq]). That said, I think you'll need to deal with Roles and Capabilities. Also, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72370/12615) as starting point. Or maybe Multisite could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter `user_has_cap` and compare the user meta fields.

The following code is based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95851/73) and *not tested*.

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse_99393_filter_cap', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Allow editing others posts only for editors from the same school.
 * Administrators can still edit those posts.
 *
 * @wp-hook user_has_cap
 * @param   array $allcaps All the capabilities of the user
 * @param   array $caps    [0] Required capability ('edit_others_posts')
 * @param   array $args    [0] Requested capability
 *                         [1] User ID
 *                         [2] Post ID
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_99393_filter_cap( $allcaps, $caps, $args )
{
    // Not our capability
    if ( 'edit_post' !== $args[0] && 'delete_post' !== $args[0] )
        return $allcaps;

    $post = get_post( $args[2] );

    // Let users edit their own posts
    if ( (int) $args[1] === (int) $post->post_author )
        $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = TRUE;

    // editor meta field is set and not empty
    if ( ! $editor_school = get_user_meta( $args[1], 'school', TRUE ) )
        return $allcaps;

    // author meta field is set and not empty
    if ( ! $author_school = get_user_meta( $post->post_author, 'school', TRUE ) )
        return $allcaps;

    if ( $author_school === $editor_school )
        $allcaps[ $caps[0] ] = TRUE;

    return $allcaps;
}
```