# Assign specific editor with custom user meta "A" to all authors with custom user meta "A" and exclude all other author access

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, content-restriction

I am looking to do the following:

Logic/layout/cores:

1. All contributors select a **school** in a custom user profile meta field
2. All contributors also select a **club** in a custom user profile meta field
3. Editors also select a **school** and a **club** (same profile fields as above)

Goal:
**The editor (user role) that has School A and Club B stored as custom user values can view/edit/publish posts made *ONLY* by contributors (user role) who also have School A and Club B stored as custom user values.**

All contributors should only be able to read/view their articles and media. (I currently am able to do that with [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30308/how-to-hide-media-uploads-by-other-users-in-the-media-menu))

[Based on this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99393/limit-post-view-and-management-to-custom-user-meta-information), I believe I'll need to be working with the following:

```
user_has_cap
get currentuserinfo
get_user_meta
```

By going through the following:

- Check current logged in user ID, user role, custom meta - SCHOOL, and custom meta - CLUB. Store values.
- If logged in user is an EDITOR, allow EDITOR to see all other users' posts ONLY if the other users have identical custom meta - SCHOOL **and** custom meta - CLUB values (to the EDITOR).
- If logged in user is a CONTRIBUTOR, allow user to only see its own posts.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to best tackle this? Any guidance is **much** appreciated!

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this or were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Partially figured out. I'll add code above shortly.