# Reorder "menu order" of attachments to another predefined order

Tags: attachments, gallery, user-interface

I want to show photos attached to a post in a gallery using the built-in system with a custom order. Currently with the `[gallery]` shortcode it is posible to order it by name, by upload date, by ID, randomly or by a custom "menú order". I guess there are more option with custom queries in templates, but I haven't looked for that yet.

I would like to order a large bunch of photos and keep them by the date they were taken  (not a core option, but that is a tangential issue), particularly as I would like eventually to continue uploading things later to the same gallery and I may get a bit confused if some photos belong between the already uploaded ones. Also, is not always easy to get the photos *uploaded* in order, even.

My problem is that a simple "post_date" orderby query is not enough for me as I still would like to change the order of a few attachment for conceptual issues after the "post_date" order. So, I would like to **have an option on the UI to automatically reorder the "menu order" to another predefined order** (i have the "EXIF created_timestamp" in mind, but it can be alphabetical, uploaded date / ID or even random), and one could continue changing manually the order on top of that.

I want to ask if there's already a plugin that does something similar to that or if there are some functions that I have to look for reference.

Comment: Interesting question, but leave off the plugin recomendation part, it's off-topic. And if you have done some research, post your effort results, it will be appreciated by the community and you can get better answers.

Comment: you could do it with a simple meta-box and custom fields. Or if you want to add it to the actual uploader UI you could have a look at `attachment_fields_to_edit` and `attachment_fields_to_save` hooks. on the right you will find a [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14776/13256) with example implementation