# How to set a conditional statement for $attachment->post_excerpt, to check for value?

Tags: attachments

I have a custom function which looks if an attachement has a certain caption value, if so the attachement is selected, like so

```
 foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            if ($attachment->post_excerpt == 'single-gallery') {
```

But how can i give a attachement two or more values and select one? So if i give an attachement the caption values of

```
single-gallery | downloads
```

it will be selected for single gallery and downloads

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not misuse the caption for such values. Just [add separate fields for those data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3097/how-can-i-add-a-url-field-to-the-attachments-window/3108#3108).

There are also [plugins for media tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/media-tags) which may fit better to your needs.

Comment: your are right but i needed a quick fix, done that. Now i can dive deeper into your code. Don't like to use a plugin, i want to add the code to functions.php. Looking for a way to add an extra  multi select checkboxes field to the attachments (single-gallery, multi-gallery, downloads) and use the values in my theme

Comment: tx for helping me get on the right track. In short i added a multi checkbox and put a conditional in my theme.

Comment: @alex Cool. Mind sharing your solution by extending your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's `explode()` function as so:

```
foreach( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    $excerpts = explode( ' | ', $attachment->post_excerpt );
    if ( is_array( $excerpts ) && in_array( 'single-gallery', $excerpts ) ) {
        //your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: tx i used your suggestion with a !is_array( $excerpts ) for caption with only one value

Comment: If it's a single value, it will output an array with just one value in it. The only time it won't be an array is if you use an empty string or something.