# greater flexibility in targeting images attached to page

Tags: images, attachments

Right now I have several images attached to my page, but I only want four of them to display in a slideshow, and then the other ones are referenced within the page's visual/html box. The problem is currently all my images attached to the page  have a post type of "attachment", and this code iterates through all of them:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'post_mime_type' => 'image',
     'post_status' => null,
     'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );

     $attachments = get_posts( $args );
      if ( $attachments ) {
       foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID , 'full','',array('rel' => $attachment->post_name));
       }
      }
    endwhile; endif; ?>
```

My question is how can I distinguish the attachments so that it only queries some of them? For example, I tried adding the post_name attribute to the $args array but that didn't do anything.

Second, when I add img tag to the visual/html content editor, and then I add a src attribute, and then I go into the visual content editor, I want a non-programmer to click on the img box, which prompts them to edit the image, and then under source it is requiring them to add the full url path, and I dont think that's intutive to a non-programmer. Is there an easier way for them to add image via content editor?

Comment: Your second question doesn't make much sense, and it could even deserve a completely new Question. A snapshot would be useful...

Comment: Any progress? Was one of the answers helpful? Do you still miss something?

Answer (score 0):

**Every file** that is uploaded in WordPress is an *Attachment*, which is a kind of post (`'post_type' => 'attachment'`).

When the file is uploaded *inside* a Post or Page, it is *attached* to that particular post/page (`'post_parent' => $post->ID`).
[image]

I can think of a solution that doesn't involves any particular coding:

- you simply have to put an order in your gallery images (`'orderby'=> 'menu_order'`) and set the number of posts (of the attachment type) to be grabbed as four (`'numberposts' => 4`).
  [image]
  <sup>[image source](http://87studios.net/psdtuts-2/how-to-create-an-instant-image-gallery-plugin-for-wordpress/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[Add a meta box to the attachment edit screen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3108/73) and use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to separate the images you want from the rest.